# Stopping edit session at start of ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, editing, mxd

I have a simple script that I use to select features from a ArcSDE database and export them to a personal.gdb.

Currently, I have to manually save and stop my edit session in the MXD so that the script can get a schema lock.

I have been trying to use arcpy.da.Editor at the start of the script to automatically end the edit session, but I have not been able to achieve that thus far.

Is this the correct way to end an edit session in the MXD I am running the script in? I would also like to be able to restart my edit session after the script runs.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

edit = arcpy.da.Editor
edit.startEditing(False, True)
print 'Stopping Edit'

# Delete Feature class from file Geodatabase
arcpy.Delete_management('C:\GIS\BlairMailer\Mailer.mdb\AddressPoint')
print 'Feature Class Deleted'

# Select by attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ( "AddressPoint", "NEW_SELECTION", "   [DISTRICT] = 'Y'" or "[DISTRICT] = 'y'")

# Export selected feature to Geodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion("AddressPoint",'C:\GIS\BlairMailer\Mailer.mdb')
print 'feature Class Exported'

# Open Mailer
os.startfile(r'C:\GIS\BlairMailer\Mailer.docx')
```

This is the returned error when I try to run the script with an active edit session.

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'startEditing' requires a 'Workspace Editor' object   but received a 'bool'
```

Answer (score 3):

As commented by @GISGe, the

> `arcpy.da.Editor` [class] takes a workspace as argument: `arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)`

whereas you have:

```
edit = arcpy.da.Editor
```

See the [Syntax section of the Editor class Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm#S2_GUID-AAE0637D-9CE2-4DAF-A306-BD21F61AF4FB)